# How to unit test catch block of this method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, nunit, rhino-mocks

I am learning unit testing. How to unit test this method using NUnit and Rhino Mock? Well I have tested `try` block and want to test `catch` block for code coverage.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AppraisalOrderIsAcceptedByEmployee(int appraisalOrderId)
{
    try
    {
        this.appraisalOrderService.SubmitAppraisalOrder(appraisalOrderId);
    }
    catch (MessageLoneException ex)
    {
        // Display validation errors
        PersistErrors(ex);

        // Remains on the same view
        return RedirectToAction("VerifyOrderDetails", new { id = appraisalOrderId });
    }
    return GetLoginRedirectCurrentUser();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `appraisalOrderService` is an interface (which in a properly architected application is a safe assumption to make) that your controller takes as constructor injection you could easily mock it with your favorite mocking framework. For example with Rhino Mocks your test might look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AppraisalOrderIsAcceptedByEmployee_Should_Redirect_To_VerifyOrderDetails_Action_If_SubmitAppraisalOrder_Throws_A_MessageLoneException()
{
    // arrange
    var appraisalOrderId = 5;
    var orderServiceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IOrderService>();
    orderServiceMock
        .Expect(x => x.SubmitAppraisalOrder(appraisalOrderId))
        .Throw(new MessageLoneException());
    var sut = new MyController(orderServiceMock);

    // act
    var actual = sut.AppraisalOrderIsAcceptedByEmployee(appraisalOrderId);

    // assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
    Assert.AreEqual("VerifyOrderDetails", result.RouteValues["action"]);
    Assert.AreEqual(appraisalOrderId, result.RouteValues["id"]);
}
```

You haven't shown what the `PersistErrors` methods is and how it behaves so it is hard to tell the proper way to test it. You might need to mock additional things if this method is using them. Given the comment you have put above it I suppose that somehow you are adding errors to the `ModelState` using the `AddModelErrorMethod`. If this is the case you could verify it in the assertion phase of your test:

```
Assert.IsFalse(sut.ModelState.IsValid);
```

and if you know the key under which you stored the error:

```
Assert.AreEqual(
    "some expected message",
    sut.ModelState["someKey"].Errors.Single().ErrorMessage
);
```

Comment: hey thank you. I have one question. As i am writing tests in anather class, should i use reflection to access private methods for test cases ?

Comment: No, you should **not** use any reflection at all. You should **not** unit test private methods. That's implementation detail. You should test the public methods that are calling those private methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably test `PersistErrors()` independently.

And `RedirectToAction` is a framework method. There's no need to test the framework.

Testing the contents of the `catch` block just for the sake of code coverage seems like going a bit too far. There's no logic involved.

You should rather test if `appraisalOrderService.SubmitApraisalOrder()` throws a `MessageLoneException` as required.

Remember the 80/20 rule. Testing the framework for coverage isn't very efficient and an a waste of your valuable time as developer IMHO.

If you still want to test the catch block in this method you can fake your service so that `FakeAppraisalOrderService.SubmitApraisalOrder()` throws a `MessageLoneException`.

Still, I'd recommend focusing your time on testing actual logic. 100% coverage is an idealized target, not a rule.

Comment: Although `RedirectToAction` is a framework method, it is being passed values which should be asserted.

Comment: @TrevorPilley what exactly would be your assertion there? That `appraisalOrderId` is still the same? I don't see any code manipulating it.

Comment: `var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.AppraisalOrderIsAcceptedByEmployee(appraisalOrderId);
Assert.AreEqual(appraisalOrderId, result.RouteValues["id"]);
Assert.AreEqual("VerifyOrderDetails", result.RouteValues["action"]);` you should be asserting that you are redirecting to the correct action and passing the appraisalOrderId back as the route value.

Comment: @TrevorPilley this is just mirroring the arguments that are being passed. Of course you can test that, but why would you? There's no logic involved. No decision to make sure is right every time. I expect the `RedirectToAction()` method to properly translate the arguments into `RouteValues`. That's testing the framework once again. But I'm aware that opinions differ here, I personally would focus on more relvant tests.

Comment: You're not testing the behavior of the framework, you're testing that the method calls a redirect to the correct action with the correct values. Part of the behavior of the method if it handles an `MessageLoneException` is that it redirects so you should confirm that with a test.